# FXMLLoader.getController() returns null

Tags: java, javafx, fxmlloader

This section of code executes when the user presses a button, and it should change the scene.
The controller of the new scene needs an instance of an object, so I thought of creating a setter method in the new controller class that accepts such object.

Though, when I `loader.getController()`, this method seems to return null, which causes a NullPointerException to be thrown, as I use try to use that controller's set method.
The new controller is instantiated in the new root node in a FXML file.

Here's the code that should load the new scene from the FXML file and do what I said above:

```
try {
Stage stage = (Stage) anchorPane.getScene().getWindow();
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent newRoot = loader.load(getClass().getResource("ViewRegistrazione.fxml"));
Scene newScene = new Scene(newRoot);
stage.setScene(newScene);
stage.setMinWidth(600);
stage.setMinHeight(400);
stage.setResizable(false);

ViewRegistrazioneController viewRegistrazioneController = loader.getController();
viewRegistrazioneController.setUser(c);
} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here's the line in the new FXML file that sets the controller:

```
<AnchorPane fx:id="anchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="EatAdvisor.clienti.ViewRegistrazioneController">
```

How can I avoid getting a NullPointerException at `viewRegistrazioneController.setUser(c);` ?

Comment: Doesn't your IDE give you a warning on `loader.load(...)` about calling a static method from a non-static context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`FXMLLoader.load(URL)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load(java.net.URL)) method you are calling is a static method. Consequently, it cannot change the state of any `FXMLLoader` instance (including `loader`) and so the controller instance in `loader` remains `null`.

You need to set the location on the `FXMLLoader` instance and then call the *instance* method [`loader.load()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/15/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#load()) taking no parameters. You can do this either by calling `setLocation(...)`:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("ViewRegistrazione.fxml"));
Parent newRoot = loader.load();
```

or by using the constructor that takes a `URL` parameter:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("ViewRegistrazione.fxml"));
Parent newRoot = loader.load();
```